# Prime generator in Python and C

Tags: python, performance, c, primes

I have written the [Rabin-Miller test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) in Python and ported it to C. But somehow, the C version is ~20 times slower on my system, and I am not sure how. Anyway, here is my code.

#### Python

```
import random
import time

def rabin_miller(n):
    if n in [2, 3, 5]:
        return True
    if n < 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    s = 0
    d = n - 1
    while d % 2 == 0:
        s += 1
        d >>= 1

    for k in range(2 ** 4):
        a = random.randrange(2, n - 1)
        x = pow(a, d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
            continue
        c = False
        for r in range(s - 1):
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
            if x == 1:
                return False
            if x == n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

for i in range(10000):
    rabin_miller(i)
```

#### C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long mod_pow(long b, long e, long m){
    if(m == 1)
        return 0;
    long c = 1;
    for(long i = 0; i < e; i++)
        c = (c * b) % m;
    return c;
}

int rabin_miller(long n){
    if(n == 2 || n == 3)
        return 1;
    if(n < 2 || n % 2 == 0)
        return 0;

    long s = 0, d = n - 1, k = 10, a, x, stop;
    while(d % 2 == 0)
        s += 1, d >>= 1;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(long i = 0; i < k; i++){
        a = (long) (((float) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (n - 3)) + 2;
        x = mod_pow(a, d, n);
        if(x == 1 || x == n - 1)
            continue;
        stop = 1;
        for(long r = 0; r < s - 1; r++){
            x = mod_pow(x, 2, n);
            if(x == 1)
                return 0;
            if(x == n - 1){
                stop = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(stop){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    for(long i = 1; i < 10000; i++){
        rabin_miller(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you are looking to improve the C code, I think ...? If so, the Python code is unnecessary and could be removed

Comment: Just put it there as a point of reference

Comment: You could at least improve the `while (d % 2 == 0)` With I think `while (~t & 1)`

Comment: I also assume you know this, but while Raben Miller is an efficient prime test, it isn't a good generator, as a sieve would be much faster for either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `long mod_pow` is very inefficient, as it takes e steps to complete, as compared to Python's approach which likely only takes `log(e)` steps. To fix this, you should use an algorithm similar to the following

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
if modulus = 1 then return 0
Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base
result := 1
base := base mod modulus
while exponent > 0
    if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
       result := (result * base) mod modulus
    exponent := exponent >> 1
    base := (base * base) mod modulus
return result
```

Comment: I see the value of `if modulus = 1 then return 0`, yet not `base := base mod modulus` aside from reduced chance of overflow in `base * base`.  Any other reason for it?

Comment: That's it. No reason to chance overflow if you don't need to. This way, it works for any base that fits the type, if the modulus is small enough.

Comment: It also doesn't take a ton of time, as it is one `mod` statement compared to up to 64 for the loop. (and some conditional branches)

Answer (score 11):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your C program in addition to the review from Oscar Smith which correctly identifies the reason for the major performance difference in the two versions.

### Use better variable names

Single letter variable names are not descriptive and not helpful to the reader of the code.

### Only call `srand` once

The call to `srand` should only be done once.  Calling it multiple times does not improve randomness.

### Use `bool` where appropriate

Since C99, the C language supports `bool`, and the `rabin_miller()` function should return a `bool` rather than an `int`.  You will need to `#include <stdbool.h>` to do this.

### Use the appropriate data type

In the original code `k` and `i` are just used as part of a loop count.  An `int` or `unsigned` would be a more appropriate type than `long` and may confer a performance advantage.  The same goes for `r` and `s`.

### Prefer `for` to `while`

The code which calculates `s` and `d` could be written a bit more succinctly and clearly, in my view, like this:

```
for(s = 0; d % 2 == 0; ++s) {
    d >>= 1;
}
```

### Simplify `for` loop termination condition

The point to the `for (r ...` loop is to simply iterate `s-1` times.  Rather than comparing `r` to `s-1` each iteration, it makes more sense to simply start the loop from 1 rather than 0 and compare with `s` directly:

```
    for(unsigned r = 1; r < s; r++) {
```

Even simpler, count down instead.  Some processors have a special instruction which does both a decrement and test for zero so here again, there may be a performance advantage on some architectures:

```
    for(unsigned r = s; r; --r) {
```

### Declare variables in as small a scope as practical

The variables `a` and `x` are only used inside the big loop and so could easily be declared only there.  Keeping the scope of variables as small as practical makes the code easier to read and understand and may give the compiler some better hints as to register allocation.

Comment: Would there be any benefit to using !(n & 0x1) over n % 2 == 0? You missed your usual point about symbolic constants over raw numbers (main).

Comment: For the first question, no, there's usually no benefit because compilers are generally smart enough to generate the same optimal code for either.  For the second, other than `k` in the original, I think that having hard coded numbers (e.g. 2, 3) in this intrinsically mathematical function is fine.

Comment: Pedantic corner `!(n & 0x1)`  is not the same as `n % 2 == 0` in the archaic one's complement. when `n<0`.

Comment: I'll concede the point if you can name *any* currently used compiler which uses one's complement. :)

Comment: Should have waited 5 minutes -- grumble grumble.

Comment: I've now cheated and edited my previous post.  In all seriousness, your point about what we can and cannot assume based on the *standard* is entirely valid.  What we see via the *implementations* is another, also valid viewpoint.

Comment: @Edward The trouble with implementation define code, as done today, is it hints at, but do not insure the future.  Much code of the past now fails due to UB of `int` overflow which _was_ reasonable consistent back-in-the-day.  I wonder about today's code that relies on common implementation behavior that will break in the future and so endeavor to product code that assumes little.

Comment: Generally I agree, but for this *particular* issue, the odds that any  future C compilers will shift to a one's complement numerical representation is very near zero.

Comment: @Edward: Regarding the "count down" advice => I would leave this up to the optimizer, it's a transformation they do routinely. [See this example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0089131a5e8a9466eb19f2d64cf08b96).

Comment: Unisys is always there to provide us with real hardware that uses non-standard numeric formats. They are currently shipping ClearPath Dorado systems that use ones'-complement arithmetic (albeit emulating the original hardware on Intel Xeon CPUs), and ClearPath Libra machines that use a sign-magnitude representation for integers. Unisys ships an ANSI C compiler for these machines. Never say never. :-)

Comment: @MatthieuM. Perhaps that's how it works on your compiler, but it's not so common for embedded systems compilers.  [updated example](https://gist.github.com/beroset/4ab0eb7c4a85678dfb2296c164014798.js)

Comment: @CodyGray: If you have access to that compiler, can you try ` !(n & 0x1)` and `n % 2 == 0` to see what they produce?

Comment: I definitely don't have access to the compiler. I only have access to Google.

Comment: @Edward: Ah, embedded... I'll still argue that you should write for correctness first and optimize later. After all, even when the optimizer generally works, sometimes manual optimizations still help (for example by reducing register pressure, etc...), so it's not exactly specific to the embedded world. But I do pity those who have to do strength reduction and other peephole optimizations by hand :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. I absolutely agree that you should write for correctness first.  Both versions I listed are correct.  To me, the count down version is more intuitive and it's definitely shorter.  The ironic thing is that the SDCC compiler *does* implement peephole optimizations, but turning count-up into count-down loops is apparently not currently in its repertoire.

Comment: I also just checked, and with this compiler, `!(n & 1)` is much shorter with that compiler and target than `n % 2 == 0`.

Comment: @Edward: The count-up/count-down operation is a strength reduction optimization but not properly a peephole one as it impacts multiple sites at once. It's a bit more involved therefore, and notably is only a "free meal" if there is no other usage of the induction variable (otherwise a fix-up of the uses is necessary which may be more costly).

Comment: [Yes, there are several popular compilers that fail to reduce the strength of `n % 2 == 0` as you might expect them to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25230552/366904). In particular, MSVC as of a few versions ago, and older versions of ICC.